# How exactly does space work with scanf?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, space

I am a math student, and I'm learning the very basics in programming in C. I need a program to read an input consisting in an array, the components of which must have certain requisites; I would like the program to ask the user for the components of the array. The user should then have to enter such components separating them with spaces. The details aren't important to get the main question across; I'll choose a simpler example then the one I am dealing with: let's say I want an array with 6 components not to contain the number 4. So I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[6];
    printf("enter components: ");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        if (a[i] == 4) printf(" \n\n4 is not allowed, try again\n\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

If I compile this and run it, and for example enter:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I will get my error message, but only after having pressed enter, that is after having entered all six components (not straight after having pressed space for the fourth time). So here are my questions (I am looking for **solutions which don't make use of strings or pointers**, unless it is impossible to do without them):

1. Is there a way to get the program to read a component (and to act accordingly) straight after its subsequent space has been entered? I'm guessing there isn't because scanf only works after the user presses enter, and not space, correct?
2. If there isn't, is there a way to get the program to read the components all at once after having pressed enter at the end, but letting the user pick up from the last right component? For example, with the above input, I would like the program to display something like this:

   ```
   4 is not allowed
   1 2 3 _
   ```

   so that the user can correct his/her input (possibly changing the first three digits as well).

Sorry if this question is too dumb! Thank you for your help!!

---

EDIT: Well, thanks for the great answers, you have all been very helpful! It's a pity I can't accept more than one.

Comment: Sorry, but error-handling and checking the input for errors are different things. Edited. if you are not against it.

Comment: Nothing in the C standard library supports this; you'll need to use a more or less platform-specific library, such as [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). What platform are you aiming for?

Comment: @ruakh I use Code Blocks in Windows; I have only used the standard library and math library and don't know any others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the bellow code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[6];
    int i;
    bool hasError = false;
    int errorIndex = 0;
    do{
        hasError = false;
        printf("enter components: ");
        for (i = 0; i < errorIndex; i++)
            printf("%d ", a[i]);

        for (i = errorIndex; i < 6; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
            if (a[i] == 4 && hasError == false){
                printf(" \n\n4 is not allowed, try again\n\n");
                hasError = true;
                errorIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }while(hasError == true);
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by bool, at line 6? My compiler doesn't understand this (undeclared), and neither do I (sorry, I'm a real beginner)

Comment: boot is a boolean type. you should include `<stdbool.h>` to use it. (Or you can change the `bool` to `int`, and the `false` to `0`)

Comment: Great, this works perfectly! I guess I'm going to have to change the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you, I hope it be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

In for loop, after each iteration, the counter add by one automatically. If you get an invalid input, you should prevent the counter increasing. To do this, just add `i--;` to your code when you give an invalid input.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[6];
    printf("enter components: ");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        if (a[i] == 4){
           printf(" \n\n4 is not allowed, try again\n\n");
           i--;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mir, this approach would have him stuck in an infinite loop... since a[i] will keep being 4!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Won't this just overwrite the wrong component with the one after it? I tried running it and I didn't get an improvement.

Comment: Why? There is a `scanf` in the beginning of the loop.
@mir-milad-hosseiny, your code is correct, but you didn't answer the question.
Emilio, you are right. This is correction for another problem in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to your terminal being in "cooked" mode.  Characters aren't even sent to the program until the user presses enter.

Comment: Ok thanks, this is what I imagined. Still, option 2. could still be possible, couldn't it?

Comment: In cooked mode, the user can't edit what you print.  Anything's possible if you turn off cooked mode.  Have a look at [`libreadline`](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), for example.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it, however I doubt I will be able to use it for my assingment. 
One last thing: I can get the program to check each component straight after it is entered (if the user presses enter after having entered each one), however If the user enters the components separating the with spaces and presses enter at the end, there is no way (using only stdio.h) to let the user start re-entering them starting from the first wrong one. Correct?

Comment: @Emilio: Well, if you count how many were correct, you can let them re-enter from there.  It's letting them edit the previously accepted ones that's more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on Mir Milad Hosseiny answer (I wrongly identified it as being an out of control infinite loop... it's actually exactly the infinite loop I describe in my comment)...

I would write a small function that has either a "white list" (things you want) or a "black list" things you don't want, and check each value to either belong or not (depending on the approach) to the list. That way you can keep a separate place where your store the values that you are willing to accept or the values you are not, so your primary function doesn't get really messy with exceptions or inclusions in the "if"

so your code would be

```
if(isAllowed(a[i]){
   myList[j] = a[i]; //j is your alternate counter
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Is there a way to get the program to print the myList so the user can modify it?

Comment: Ok, Ben Voigt just answered this.

Comment: right, my point is that presumably you want to actually USE those 6 numbers for something (other than just printing them back).  So, you're going to wind up with a userInput[6] somewhere, which is the array that will store the numbers.  So, my advice would be to put the  scanf in an infinite loop (not based on any int) and stay in it until you have your 6 valid values. Increment the valid value index only when you have a valid value and use that index in the userInput array.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
int i,a[6];
for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
 scan: scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
for (int i=0;i<6;i++) if (a[i]==4) {
 printf("4 is not allowed. re-enter the last %d numbers\n",6-i);
 goto scan;
}
```

note that in most case, it's better to avoid using `goto`, but in this case I think that it's natural.

If you really want, you can print the first `i` numbers (before the `goto`), but it's complicated (and platform-depended) to let the user change those numbers.

Comment: Ok, this would still require the user to re-enter the last 6-i components manually though.

Comment: I thought that this is what you want. if not, change the body of the second loop to:
`printf("4 is not allowed. re-enter the %dth number\n",i+1);
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
i--;`
(The `i--` is to recheck `a[i]`)

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is what I wanted. What I meant was that the user would have to enter the first i components, but on second thought this wouldn't be necessary, since they are already stored in the a[i]s. Thank you, without the possibility of getting the program to print the first i components, with the possibility for the user to edit them,  this seems like the best solution!